# Associations: Prevent Save if the Collection as a Whole is Invalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I need to validate a model containing an associated collection which requires
a field to be unique within a `has_many` collection.

For example, if I have the following classes:

```
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :match_items, dependent: :destroy
  validates_associated :match_items
end

class MatchItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :match
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_type, scope: :match_id
end
```

I create a Match like this:

```
items = [
  MatchItem.new(user_type: 'test'),
  MatchItem.new(user_type: 'test')
]
match = Match.new(match_items: items)
match.save # Erroneously returns true
```

I want the Match creation to fail.

While the uniqueness validator in the MatchItem class *does* prevent the collection from containing multiple user types, I would prefer that the Match creation fail. Instead, the match is created without error, although it contains only one of the specified match items.

I think the problem is that `validates_associated` calls `valid?` on each MatchItem before saving the Match, but each MatchItem, before it is added to the Match, *is* valid on its own.

What's the best way to prevent the Match from saving when its match_items collection does not contain unique values?

Comment: Why can't you just wrap everything in an AR.transaction block and use `create!` ?

Comment: @PhilipHallstrom The reason that I can't wrap this in a transaction with a `create!` call is because it doesn't throw an error, despite the fact that only one of the associated match items is saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is an open issue ([#11851](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/11851)) in the rails project. As Peter helped point out, the problem here comes when you build the records vs creating them separately. As a work around for now, I am just creating all the objects before assigning them to the collection.

```
# This one fails properly
items = MatchItem.create([ { user_type: 'test' }, { user_type: 'test' } ])
Match.create!(match_items: items)

# While this one succeeds when it shouldn't
items = [
  MatchItem.new(user_type: 'test'),
  MatchItem.new(user_type: 'test')
]
match = Match.new(match_items: items)
match.save # Erroneously returns true
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to understand this myself.  The following appears in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

> 4.3.4 When are Objects Saved? When you assign an object to a has_many association, that object is automatically saved (in order to update
>   its foreign key). If you assign multiple objects in one statement,
>   then they are all saved.
>
> If any of these saves fails due to validation errors, then the
>   assignment statement returns false and the assignment itself is
>   cancelled.
>
> If the parent object (the one declaring the has_many association) is
>   unsaved (that is, new_record? returns true) then the child objects are
>   not saved when they are added. All unsaved members of the association
>   will automatically be saved when the parent is saved.
>
> If you want to assign an object to a has_many association without
>   saving the object, use the collection.build method.

As an experiment, could you try creating the `Match` without any `MatchItem`s and then assigning the `MatchItem`s to see if none get assigned?

Comment: If I create the Match first like you suggest and then assign the MatchItems using `match.match_items = items`, the record *does* fail when I try to save. Do you think the original problem is just a bug in rails?

Comment: I don't know if it's a bug or a feature, since the documentation isn't clear. Since the associated items are not actually _part_ of the item, creating the set of them is not naturally atomic. The validations depend on the "master" id which requires creating the "master" record, so it's not easy to rollback once you get started with the creation process.